# how to get sql queries from DAO classes using hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am using hibernate for database activity in my spring mvc application.I also use spring AOP to do some other activity after control comes to any controller.

Is it possible to get the sql queries which are being executed in DAO classes in the advices of aspect class..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To see the sql which is produce by hibernate request. You have :
1. to add the following configuration in hibernate.cfg.xml :

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

2. use the properly log level :

   log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG

   log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE

[See the config doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging)